# Mobile SDK error: OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED

Tags: java, android, mobile, sdk, here-api

I have downloaded and registered for the evaluation of the Here Premium Mobile SDK for Android.  However, during initialization an error is returned: OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED.  Is there something I am doing wrong?  Is there something that HERE needs to do centrally on their end to enable the evaluation?

```
        mapFragment = (MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);
    mapFragment.init(new OnEngineInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(OnEngineInitListener.Error error) {

            Log.wtf("Main", "error: " + error.toString());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you registered the evaluation you was asked about a namespace.
That namespace is actually the `applicationId` of your application (the one that you put in `build.gradle`).
If you cannot remember the namespace that you provided during registration just register a new evaluation with the applicationId you are using. The original namespace you provided isn't available to retrieve from the dashboard.
It took me a couple of hours to find out.

Comment: Thanks!  That was it.  Suggestions for HERE team.  1) Make the namespace entered available on the dashboard.  2)  Return a less ambiguous error for this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure you have updated your AndroidManifest.xml with your evaluation values:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity 
    ...
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.appid" android:value="your evaluation value"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.apptoken" android:value="your evaluation value"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.license.key" android:value="your evaluation value"/>

    <service android:exported="true" android:label="HereMapService" android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService" android:process="global.Here.Map.Service.v2">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```